# Can't open Image on mac with PIL

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

So I have a short python script that takes in a base64 string that represents an image, and then opens a preview of that image.

Heres my script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
import sys
import base64

IMAGE_NAME = "temp.png"

def do_some_stuff(args):
    if len(args) != 2:
        return

    with open(IMAGE_NAME, "wb") as image_file:
        image_file.write(base64.decodebytes(args[1].encode('ascii')))

    image = Image.open(IMAGE_NAME)
    image.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_some_stuff(sys.argv)
```

It seems to work okay, except for when it gets time to show the image I'm greeted with this error:

`FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Preview.app) failed with error -43.`

Does anyone know why this error is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas, that is the entire error message that comes out

Comment: and add base64 string which you use. Maybe it is not correct image. OR maybe it is not `.png` but other format.

Comment: @furas the base64 is a valid png string, ive confirmed that myself - youll have to take my word since the image i used is a pic of my face i dont wanna upload. Updated question with more info though

Comment: maybe use `import os` `print(os.getcwd())` to see in which folder python runs this code - (Current Working Directory). It should write in this directory - if it has all permission for this.

Comment: @furas i figured it out, just posted an answer - i appreciate your attempts at helping!

Comment: so now you can mark your answer as acceped :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a bit more, it seems this error from `FSPathMakeRef` means that the file was not found. So I looked inside my applications folder, and Preview was right there!

When i clicked get info i noticed it was in the `/System/Applications/` folder and not in `/Applications`, so it seems PIL is referencing the wrong location.

[image]

My guess is that the application was moved in Catalina and PIL just hasn't been updated yet.

Anyway to fix it I just made a symbolic link where PIL was looking like this:

```
ln -s /System/Applications/Preview.app /Applications/Preview.app
```

and it worked like a charm!