# macos pillow could not show image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've tried to make pillow show a picture in macOS.

```
from PIL import pillow
im = Image.open('exapmle.png')
im.show()
```

and here's the error:

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Preview.app) failed with error -43.
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: I think this is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001444/2836621

Answer (score 0):

the solution from the linked answer in the comments works well:

```
ln -s /System/Applications/Preview.app /Applications/Preview.app
```