# Getting an error when using PIL img.show()

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I have an image in my directory, say "image.png". This is the code I run:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("image.png")
img.show()
```

And the error message that pops up is: "FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Preview.app) failed with error -43."

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open Image on mac with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001218/cant-open-image-on-mac-with-pil)